# $f(x)=\frac{9x}{x^2+7x-8}$ as a series at center $c=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have to represent
$$f(x)=\frac{9x}{x^2+7x-8}$$ as a series at center $c=0$, no Taylor Series or Maclaurin Series please (not sure if that even helps, haven't learned about it yet).

What I'm really trying to do is get this thing to look like $\frac{a}{1-r}$ so it can be represented as: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^n$$

I seriously don't have a clue how to make the center at $c=0$... The denominator factors, but it doesn't seem to help.

Can someone show me how to rewrite that $f(x)$ so I can represent it as a series? Thanks

Comment: hint: $x^2+7x-8=(x+8)(x-1)$ and taylor series of $1/(x+1)$ center at zero is $1-x+x^2+...$

Comment: @Simple. No Taylor series

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're dead set on using geometric series, try partial fractions, since the numerator is of lower degree than the denominator. In particular, I use the [Heaviside cover-up method](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ejorloff/suppnotes/suppnotes03/h.pdf), but the algebraic way works too!
$$ \frac{9x}{x^2 + 7x - 8} = \frac{9x}{(x+8)(x-1)} = \frac{8}{x+8} + \frac{1}{x-1}. $$

From here, we can rewrite the two functions as
$$
\frac{8}{x+8} + \frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{x}{8}} - \frac{1}{1-x}
$$

You can now apply your geometric series formula to these two functions.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite $$f(x)=\frac{9x}{x^2+7x-8}$$ as
$$f(x)=-9x\,\,\,\color{red}{\frac{1}{8-7x-x^2}}$$ Make the long division of the red  term and multiply the result by $-9x$

Comment: Hey, thanks for no Taylor Series (we're getting there *tomorrow*), I told you I'd remember you when I learn it ;)

Comment: I'm not understanding how this would work, it could be because I'm bad at long division. I certainly don't expect you to do it for me since I already got a better answer (for me)